# Keras CNN training: Cannot use nested list as Input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, input

(Edited to include dataset and model code)

I'm training a Keras CNN 2d matrix. I'm creating my own training dataset, in which each matrix cell has the shape of `[[list], int]`. The cell's first list item is the product of a string class that I converts to list (using `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical`):

```
cell[0] = to_categorical(
                rnd_type-1, num_classes=num_types)
```

the second is a simple int:

```
cell[1] = random.randint(0, max_val)
```

The dataset creation function:

```
def make_data(num_of_samples, num_types, max_height, grid_x, grid_y):
grids_list = []
target_list = []
target = 0
for _ in range(num_of_samples):
    # create empty grid 
    grid = [[[[],0] for i in range(grid_y)] for j in range(grid_x)]
    for i in range(grid_x):
        for j in range(grid_y):
            rnd_type = random.randint(
                0, num_types)
            # get random class 
            # and convert to cat list 
            cat = to_categorical(
                rnd_type-1, num_classes=num_types)
            # get random type 
            rnd_height = random.randint(0, max_height)
            # inject the two values into the cell 
            grid[i][j] = [cat, rnd_height]
            # get some target value 
            target += rnd_type * 5 + random.random()*5
    target_list.append(target)
    grids_list.append(grid)
    # make np arrs out of the lists 
    t = np.array(target_list)
    g = np.array(grids_list)
return t, g
```

my model is created using `model = models.create_cnn(grid_size, grid_size, 2, regress=True)` in which (I assumed) the `Input` depth is 2.

The model creation code:

```
num_types = 20
max_height = 50
num_of_samples = 10
grid_size = 10
epochs = 5000


# get n results of X x Y grid with target
targets_list, grids_list = datasets.make_data(
    num_of_samples, num_types, max_height, grid_size, grid_size)
    
split = train_test_split(targets_list, grids_list,
                         test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
(train_attr_X, test_attr_X, train_grids_X, test_grids_X) = split

# find the largest value in the training set and use it to
# scale values to the range [0, 1]

max_target = train_attr_X.max()
train_attr_Y = train_attr_X / max_target
test_attr_Y = test_attr_X / max_target

model = models.create_cnn(grid_size, grid_size, 2, regress=True)
```

I however cannot train it given this error: `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).`

Comment: Please show us your code

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question:

`model` can only accept `int` as depth. Therefore, the depth of my matrix must by a list of int `len`, not a 2D matrix. For that reason, the way to merge class data with continuous field `rnd_height` is:

- class => `cat = to_categorical`
- `cell = np.append(cat, [rnd_height])`

This way, `cat` list is added with the `rnd_height` value.
The whole dataset function now look like this:

```
def make_data(num_of_samples, num_types, max_height, grid_x, grid_y):
    grids_list = []
    target_list = []
    target = 0
    for _ in range(num_of_samples):
        grid = [[[False, False] for i in range(grid_y)] for j in range(grid_x)]
        for i in range(grid_x):
            for j in range(grid_y):
                rnd_type = random.randint(
                    0, num_types)
                cat = to_categorical(
                    rnd_type-1, num_classes=num_types)
                rnd_height = random.randint(0, max_height)
                cell = np.append(cat, [rnd_height])
                grid[i][j] = cell

                # simulate simple objective function
                if rnd_type < num_types/5:
                    target += rnd_height * 5

        target_list.append(target)
        grids_list.append(grid)

        t = np.array(target_list)
        g = np.array(grids_list)
    # return grids and targets
    return g, t
```